# Is it possible to interpolate between two different master fonts?

Tags: fonts, animation, interpolation

I know that it is possible to interpolate between different masters of one font but is it somehow possible to interpolate between two different fonts? Lets say Times and Helvetica?
It is for experimental use and dont need to give perfect results.

What software can I use to generate a new interpolated desktop font from two different fonts?

Is there an app to generate a variable webfont that could be animated from one font to the other?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/118874/36230) method for Blender and [this](https://css-tricks.com/many-tools-shape-morphing/) article about live morphing on the web.

Comment: Just a quick comment that while this is possible, they have totally different forms of 'g' (double vs. single story) so you might want to tweak this manually when you produce your font. And the italics will have a different 'a' too.

Comment: So do you want to use this on a website? Dozens of font versions for just a bit of animation seems quite crazy anyway. Probably better to convert that bit that you want to animate to an svg and animate that through animation software or I believe there are even svg morph scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how useful this will be for your requirements, but if you don't need perfect results then it is kind of possible using Adobe Illustrator using a step blend. If you don't have access to Illustrator, then Inkscape is free and also has an Interpolation extension.

If you have a pair of letters from two different fonts, expand them to outlines, select both, and add a blend, then open the blend options and choose a step value, with the required number of steps. Obviously this would need to be done for each letter pair.

Here's an example for the letters x and y from a serif and san-serif font, each with a 4 step blend. This example was made with Illustrator.

[image]

You could perhaps add extra anchors to the shape to get a better transition, but there's no real control over what direction each anchor will move/morph.  Perhaps software such as After Effects or Blender would give more control.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to truly do this using web fonts as you say in the question is to use [*variables fonts*](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/typography/variable-fonts/), which [has surprisingly good support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=variable-fonts) given it's a new technology for the web.

You'd have to create your own variable font based on the two fonts that you want to animate (granted you have permission to do so). I don't know of any software that could do that for you. A couple posts that I've found detailing how to create these fonts include [Robofont's](https://robofont.com/documentation/how-tos/creating-variable-fonts/) and [Glyphs'](https://glyphsapp.com/tutorials/creating-a-variable-font).

To find existing variable fonts, see [V-Fonts.com](https://v-fonts.com/) or [Axis Praxis](https://www.axis-praxis.org/specimens/__DEFAULT__). For creative uses of variable fonts, [this CSS-Tricks post](https://css-tricks.com/weird-things-variable-fonts-can-do/) is pretty good.

---

If you don't really need a true web font (say the text is fixed or something similar). It would probably be easiest to change the text into an SVG and then use something like After Effects to animate the transition. The next easiest thing would be to again convert to SVG and then use an SVG morph animation to go between the two, using something like [GSAP's MorphSVG plugin](https://greensock.com/morphSVG), [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/), or [Kute.js SVG plugin](http://thednp.github.io/kute.js/svg.html) (this is the first time I've seen this one) to keep it easy (though [it is possible](https://codeburst.io/svg-morphing-the-easy-way-and-the-hard-way-c117a620b65f#83c0) to do it by hand).

Answer (score 0):

On character per character basis you can do this in ie coreldraw. You can use two shapes to interpolate between them easily. You would get best results if you would manipulate the character with less nodes (Helvetica) to have the same number of them as the same character in the other (Times). This way you can control the interpolation process to get best results.

You can then take the interpolation to export/import into ie FontLab and create an actual font.